# Accessing JSON data when PhantomJS onResourceReceived is triggered (ESPN fantasy football draft app)

Tags: javascript, json, phantomjs

So I'm trying to write a hook into ESPN fantasy football's HTML lite draft page to cross-reference player ranking lists (from a CSV file) to eliminate already-drafted players from the available pool. I've done this by hand in the past: but with a 16-team draft by the late rounds, it's nearly impossible to keep up since by then no one really knows who the players are.

I'm very much a Javascript and PhantomJS newbie, so please don't laugh.

At this point, I can see the page.onResourceReceived metadata in my console as the AJAX polls the PhantomJS instance. But I can't figure out how to access the data actually being received by the "browser". According to Chrome's inspector, the "Preview" tab under the Network Inspector tab -- either a time sync signal or the data of the actual player who was drafted is being sent to the browser in JSON format.

Long story short, how do I get the actual JSON data when I receive the page.onResourceReceived metadata?

(P.S. I know I commented out phantom.exit(); that's to keep the script from terminating after the redirect and onLoad is complete--I need to keep it running to listen for the draft updates)

```
var draft = 'http://games.espn.go.com/ffl/htmldraft?leagueId=1246633&teamId=8&fromTeamId=8';
var draftURL = encodeURIComponent(draft);

var page = require('webpage').create(),
    server = 'https://r.espn.go.com/espn/memberservices/pc/login',
    data = 'SUBMIT=1&failedLocation=&aff_code=espn_fantgames&appRedirect=' + draftURL + '&cookieDomain=.go.com&multipleDomains=true&username=[redacted]&password=[redacted]&submit=Sign+In';

page.onResourceReceived = function (response) {
    console.log('Response (#' + response.id + ', stage "' + response.stage + '"): ' + JSON.stringify(response));
};

page.open(server, 'post', data, function (status) {
    if (status !== 'success') {

        console.log('Unable to post!');
    } else {

        page.render('example.png');
        //console.log(page.content)
    }
    //phantom.exit();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The following version of your script will just grab and return the entire contents of the URL you are accessing.  You are not really going to get useful json data, I don't think, just an html page, unless I'm missing something.  In my tests, all I get is html:

```
var draft = 'http://games.espn.go.com/ffl/htmldraft?leagueId=1246633&teamId=8&fromTeamId=8';
var draftURL = encodeURIComponent(draft);

var page = require('webpage').create(),
server = 'https://r.espn.go.com/espn/memberservices/pc/login',
data = 'SUBMIT=1&failedLocation=&aff_code=espn_fantgames&appRedirect=' + draftURL + '&cookieDomain=.go.com&multipleDomains=true&username=[redacted]&password=[redacted]&submit=Sign+In';

page.open(server, 'post', data, function (status) {
    if (status == 'success') {
        var delay, checker = (function() {

        var html = page.evaluate(function () {
          var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
          return document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].outerHTML;
        });

        if (html) {
          clearTimeout(delay);
          console.log(html);
          phantom.exit();
        }
      });

      delay = setInterval(checker, 100);
    }
    else {
        phantom.exit();
    }
});
```

Comment: if I understand correctly, you need to call the
    page.onResourceReceived = function (response) {
    };
callback somewhere to get any response from AJAX events

Answer (score 0):

Currently, phantomjs doesn't include the response body in the `onResponseReceived` events.
You could instead [slimerjs](http://slimerjs.org/), which mirrors the phantomjs, but does allow you to access response.body (which should have the JSON data).  Example here:

http://darrendev.blogspot.jp/2013/11/saving-downloaded-files-in-slimerjs-and.html

Alternatively, you could write a chrome extension and create a content script that grabs the data.